# Fuzzy choice between a variable number of sets

Tags: algorithm, probability, fuzzy-logic

I was wondering which is the simplest and most configurable way to obtain what I need in the following situation:

- I have a counter, let's call it `X` that will be used to extract one of the sets
- I have a variable number of sets `S1, S2, ..` which can be considered [total ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) between themselves
- I want to mix these sets in a fuzzy way so that for `X = 0` it will give me `S1`, for, let's say, `X = 20` it will give me `S1` with 70% chance, and `S2` with 30% chance
- Increasing `X` will decrease probability of `S1` until 0% while increasing `S2` up to 100%, then there can be a zone in which it will always give me `S2`
  until a new threshold for which `S2` will start to decrease and `S3` will start getting its chance and so on

I know how to do it by hardcoding everything, but since it will need some tweaking I would like to apply a solution which easily allows me to configure how many sets I have and the single thresholds (start/end of increasing probability and start/end of decreasing prob). Of course I don't need any intersection between more than 2 sets each and a linear increase/decrease of probability is ok.. any good clues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the distribution of your probabilities, you could use Bernstein polynomials:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial

These can be efficiently computed using de Casteljau's algorithm (basically it does DP on the recursion in the obvious way):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau's_algorithm

http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/de-casteljau.html

What you get as a result will be a set of weights on the distributions.  To select one of your sets, you just generate a uniform random variable in [0,1] then choose the set it lands in based on these weights.

Here is some code in python which does this:

```
import random

#Selects one of the n sets with a weight based on x
def pick_a_set(n, x):

    #Compute bernstein polynomials
    weights = [ [ float(i == j)  for j in range(n) ] for i in range(n) ]
    for k in range(n):
        for j in range(n-k-1):
            for i in range(n):
                weights[j][i] = weights[j][i] * (1.0 - x) + weights[j+1][i] * x

    #Select using weights
    u = random.random()
    for k in range(n):
        if u < weights[0][k]:
            return k
        u -= weights[0][k]
    return 0
```

Comment: Seems an elegant solution, let me try it.. thanks in the meanwhile!

Comment: I adapted it to my language and situation, by tweaking `x` I'm able to spread differently over the various sets but I don't have too much clear how to manage different spreads, should I use different `x`s? I promise to take a deeper look to the maths, I'm just too lazy in these days ;)

Comment: If you want to tweak the spreads, you basically have to tweak the knot vector of the spline.  Again from that web page I linked:  http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-mod-knot.html

Comment: And for more local control of the spread, you could switch to B-spline basis functions (which are basically localized versions of the Bernstein polynomials).  All the relevant material is again on that web page. :)  http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/